# Encrypt file with openssl with secure strings

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a file with openssl in c++.
I am using the examplecode in [evp-encrypt.cxx](https://wiki.openssl.org/images/5/5d/Evp-encrypt-cxx.tar.gz) where a new datatype called `secure_sting` is used for the encryption.
My problem is that I dont know how to read the file in a way that i can still use the `secure_string` datatype to encrypt.

The important code part is:

```
template <typename T>
struct zallocator
{
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef value_type* pointer;
    typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef const value_type& const_reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

    pointer address (reference v) const {return &v;}
    const_pointer address (const_reference v) const {return &v;}

    pointer allocate (size_type n, const void* hint = 0) {
        if (n > std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T))
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        return static_cast<pointer> (::operator new (n * sizeof (value_type)));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
        OPENSSL_cleanse(p, n*sizeof(T));
        ::operator delete(p); 
    }
    
    size_type max_size() const {
        return std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof (T);
    }
    
    template<typename U>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef zallocator<U> other;
    };

    void construct (pointer ptr, const T& val) {
        new (static_cast<T*>(ptr) ) T (val);
    }

    void destroy(pointer ptr) {
        static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T();
    }

#if __cpluplus >= 201103L
    template<typename U, typename... Args>
    void construct (U* ptr, Args&&  ... args) {
        ::new (static_cast<void*> (ptr) ) U (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
    }

    template<typename U>
    void destroy(U* ptr) {
        ptr->~U();
    }
#endif
};

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, zallocator<char> > secure_string;
using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)>;

void gen_params(byte key[KEY_SIZE], byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE]);
void aes_encrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const secure_string& ptext, secure_string& ctext);
void aes_decrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], const secure_string& ctext, secure_string& rtext);

// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 evp-encrypt.cxx -o evp-encrypt.exe -lcrypto
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Load the necessary cipher
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc());

    // plaintext, ciphertext, recovered text
    secure_string ptext = "secret_text"; 
    secure_string ctext, rtext;

    byte key[KEY_SIZE], iv[BLOCK_SIZE];
    gen_params(key, iv);
  
    aes_encrypt(key, iv, ptext, ctext);
    aes_decrypt(key, iv, ctext, rtext);
```

I would like to have something like:

```
    ...
    // Load the necessary cipher
    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_256_cbc());
    
    // Read file
    ifstream f("plain.txt");
    string str;
    if(f){
    ostringstream aa;
    aa << f.rdbuf();
    str = aa.str();
    }

    // plaintext, ciphertext, recovered text
    secure_string ptext = str;
    secure_string ctext, rtext;
    ...
```

However this way I get following error:

```
 error: conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to non-scalar type ‘secure_string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, zallocator<char> >}’ requested
```

How could i read the file while using the `secure_string` or is the a better option to solve this problem without `secure_string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ptext = str.c_str(); solved the problem